# <strong> tags make space disappear/collapse?

Tags: javascript, html

Bit of an odd one:

I'm making an input element that displays suggested results, and highlights the input value as a substring of each result.

So for example if I typed 'cat' it would suggest and highlight **cat**egory

I'm just adding a strong tag to the result: `content.innerHTML =` ${arr[x].substr(0, index)}<strong>${arr[x].substr(index, match.length)}</strong>${arr[x].substr(index+match.length)}`;`

Stripped down codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/WNEYojM)

My problem - which I can't seem to replicate in the codepen above despite it being the same innerHTML code - is that if the match is next to a space, that space disappears. Eg: 'tes' => 'This is a**tes**t'.

The space *is* in the html (below), and the string outputs correctly to the console, so I feel like this has to be down to the strong tag?

[image]

No doubt I'll kick myself when someone points out my mistake, but I just can't see it

Comment: Take off the flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot of the dev tools I can see that the containing div is a flexbox, where the codepen it is not. It is the flexbox that is causing this.

See snippet below

```js
const content = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

const arr = ["Red square", "Blue circle", "Green rectangle"];
const match = "rec";

content.forEach((element) => {
  for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    if (arr[x].toUpperCase().indexOf(match.toUpperCase()) !== -1) {
      const index = arr[x].toUpperCase().indexOf(match.toUpperCase());
      element.innerHTML = `${arr[x].substr(0, index)}<strong>${arr[x].substr(
        index,
        match.length
      )}</strong>${arr[x].substr(index + match.length)}`;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.content {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 20rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.withFlex {
  display: flex;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>No Flexbox</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div>With Flexbox</div>
  <div class="content withFlex"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks Steve, I hate to think how long it would've taken me to spot that! Is there a reason why Flexbox does this? Is it because the text isn't in a div?

Comment: Correct. Flexbox formats the children of the element with `display: flex;` on it. In your example, Flexbox looks at the text before, the strong, and the text after as three different child elements. If you wrap the entire string in a div or a span, then it is only applying the flexbox to the wrapped element, and not the content inside.

Comment: This is a helpful reference that I use: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/